# GetFeatureInfo on mouse hover on feature in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers, popup, getfeatureinfo, mouse-position, mouse-cursor

I am able to get popup onclick on the feature but want to get popup also on mouse hover on the feature (polygon,point). Can anyone help me out.
For onclick I used below code -

```
var feature_onClick;
map.on('click', function(evt) {

    feature_onClick = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        console.log(feature);
        return feature;
      });


  if (feature_onClick) {
    var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');
    console.log(feature_onClick.getProperties().name);
    overlay.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
     content.innerHTML = feature_onClick.getProperties().name;
     container.style.display = 'block';
     }
});
```

For mouse hover I am using below code but unable to get pop up. Only cursor changes to pointer.

```
map.on('pointermove', function(e) {
  if (e.dragging) {
    $(element).popover('destroy');
    return;
  }
  var pixel = map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent);
  var hit = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(pixel);
  map.getTarget().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply reuse your click code and change it pointermove/hover, although I presume you only want the popup visible when over a feature, so there's an `else` clause to hide it.

```
var feature_onClick;
map.on('click', function(evt) {

    feature_onClick = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        console.log(feature);
        return feature;
      });


  if (feature_onClick) {
    var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');
    console.log(feature_onClick.getProperties().name);
    overlay.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
     content.innerHTML = 'CLICK ' + feature_onClick.getProperties().name;
     container.style.display = 'block';
     }
});

    var feature_onHover;
    map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {

        feature_onHover = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
            console.log(feature);
            return feature;
          });

      if (feature_onHover) {
        var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');
        console.log(feature_onHover.getProperties().name);
        overlay.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
         content.innerHTML = 'HOVER ' + feature_onHover.getProperties().name;
         container.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
         container.style.display = 'none';
      }
    });
```

Comment: But there is one problem, i want both thing to work at a time i.e pop on mouse hover and also popup on mouseclick. But, only one thing (hover) is working with following code. I lost onclick popup.

Comment: I think you would need two separate popup content elements, one for click and one for hover.

Comment: I tried creating two popup but didn't worked, I guess I am making mistake somewhere. I will be highly obliged if you go through my code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vk02923/jxk8tz4s/5/ this is the code I am using, in this i have created 2popups but not getting desired results.

Comment: I couldn't get hover to work at all in your code as some of the second popup setup seems to be missing.  But both click and hover work with just one popup, I added the words HOVER and CLICK to the displays to show what was happening.