# Tooltips In PostGIS+GeoServer

Tags: postgis, geoserver, style

I currently have a layer in GeoServer which consists of a number of PostGIS geometries. They are given color by a color column which is read in as part of the GeoServer style.

I now need to add tooltips to some of the shapes, preferably by adding a new column to the PostGIS table with the geometries and colors. Is there a way to do this using only PostGIS and GeoServer?

As a simplistic example assume I had a series of dots representing major cities, and I wanted a user to be able to move a mouse over the dot in openlayers to see the "City, Country" in a tooltip. In some cases that information may not be available (is null), in which case no tooltip should be shown.

I was thinking the answer was to create a TextSymbolizer label, but don't know how to get that to hide until mouseover.

Comment: tooltips are usually a client side issue, look at getfeatureinfo questions combined with the name of your client library e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298216/getfeatureinfo-on-mouse-hover-on-feature-in-openlayers-3

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to eliminate any custom code on the client side as I have to support multiple clients. I gave up and ended up just going to a GeoJSON solution and telling folks where to get the tooltip from those properties.